# How to calculate age by day, month and year in in trigger update SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using this code but something is wrong.

I tried to use many codes but failed to achieve the equation.

I enter to calculate the age add day in day and month in month and year in year

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_DeasignTeamMonthly]
ON [dbo].[StudentData]
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.StudentData 
    SET [Day] = DATEDIFF(DAY, StudentData.DateOfBirth,[dbo].StudentData.DateToDay) / 365

    UPDATE dbo.StudentData 
    SET [Month] = MONTH([dbo].StudentData.DateToDay) - 1

    UPDATE dbo.StudentData 
    SET [Year] = YEAR([dbo].StudentData.DateToDay) - YEAR([dbo].StudentData.DateOfBirth)
END
```

[image: Please check this screenshot to see what I want]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: iam using MS SQL

Comment: Do you want the duration between birth date and the present as the date format? e.g. if the birth date was 1990-07-01 and present date is 2021-10-01, is the answer 31-02-30? (template date is yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: yea i want to add day and month and year in the normal way

Comment: What needs to be calculated when rows are deleted? And why do you calculate and store something that changes **every single day**? Tomorrow, without any row being modified the values you calculate today will be incorrect. This seems like a big [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). And why do you need this precision?

Comment: Why not use a computed column?

Comment: @SMor I'm not even sure these calculations are valid anyway. What is the difference between `2021-01-05` and `2021-03-04`? Is it 1 month and 27 days or 1 month and 30 days?

Comment: oh sorry no deleted i want only to add day and month and year In other words, I want to know the exact date of birth, how old are years, months and days, for example, my date of birth is 01-12-1987 iam today have 14 dayes and 10 monthes and 33 years i want this only

Comment: It doesn't make sense to create a trigger for something like this. A function, stored procedure or something like that makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a stored procedure for calculating for this purpose, you could using it in anywhere that you need (trigger, other stored procedure ,)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CalcDurationRange
    @StartDT DATETIME,
    @EndDT DATETIME,
    @Year INT OUT,
    @Month INT OUT,
    @Day INT OUT
AS 
    DECLARE @xDate DATETIME = DATEADD(YEAR,YEAR(@EndDT)-YEAR(@StartDT),@StartDT)

    IF(@xDate>@EndDT)
        SET @xDate = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@xDate)
    
    SET @Year = DATEDIFF(YEAR,@StartDT,@xDate)   
    SET @Month = DATEDIFF(MONTH,@xDate,@EndDT)
        
    IF(DATEADD(MONTH,@Month,@xDate)>@EndDT)
        SET @Month = @Month -1  
     
    SET @Day = DATEDIFF(DAY,DATEADD(MONTH,@Month,@xDate),@EndDT)
GO
```

sample of using this SP :

```
DECLARE @xYear INT, @xMonth INT, @xDay INT
EXEC CalcDurationRange 
    '1987-12-01',
    '2021-10-01',
    @xYear  OUT,
    @xMonth OUT,
    @xDay OUT
    
PRINT @xYear         
PRINT @xMonth
PRINT @xDay
```